# Find total cycle in graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, permutation-cycles

How to know total cycle of graph that have 5 vertices?
The graph looks like star below 
First cycle have to be greater than 3 edge so
$5C3$=10
Then for 4 vertices : there are $5C4=5$ but there are 3 possible shape like trapezium then candy shape and sand watch so 5x3=15
But im not sure for 5 vertices : $5C5$ 
How can i find it and is there easy way? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your yellow drawing is not a [cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph). Moreover, you have to consider the order of vertices in each cycle (which gives a specific choice of edges). For $3$ vertices it doesn't matter, but for the other cases it does. Since the graph is complete, for each cycle of length $k$ you have $\frac12(k-1)!$ possible permutations. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Thankyou for answering my question! Do you mean for 5 vertices there are $ \frac{(5-1)!}{2}$? But for 4 vertices there are $\frac{(4-1)}{2} *5C4 $ am i right? For circular permutation why it has to be divided by 2?

Comment: That's right. You have to divide by $2$ because the graph is not oriented. For instance, on $3$ vertices $a,b,c$, $(a-b,b-c,c-a)$ and $(c-b,b-a,a-c)$ are the same cycle.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  thankyou so much really appreciate for the help!!